# Select query from multiple textboxes c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am still fairly new to both c# and SQL so please keep that in mind. I searched the site but couldn't find an answer.

I am building a basic ASP web form in C# that connect to a mysql database and populates a gridview with the results.

I have two text boxes on the web page: Phone number and User ID.
I then have a button which when clicked runs the following code:

```
        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    //SQL 
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from message where phone_number like @PatientMob and user_ID like @UserID, conn);
                    //Paramaters
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter(@"PatientMob", MySqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = PatientMobile.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter(@"UserID", MySqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = UserID.Text;

                    MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    adp.Fill(ds);
                    gridview.DataSource = ds;
```

..etc

My question is, how do I format the query so that it works even if only one textbox is filled in? 
At the moment, if I enter a phone number but do not enter the user ID, the results are showing people with that phone number who have nothing entered into the user ID field.

I will be adding more text boxes later for title, first name, surname..etc and need a solution that will work with any combination of fields filled in or not filled in.

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of LIKE operator just use Equalto(=) operator.

Comment: Also, at the end of cmd.add parameters, use string.IsNullOrEmpty(PatientMobile.Text) ? DBNull.Value : PatientMobile.Text;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any great way to do this, unfortunately, but you do have a few options.

1. Build the string dynamically

Something like this:

```
List<string> wheres = new List<string>();
List<MySqlParameter> parameters = new List<MySqlParameter>();

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PatientMobile.Text))
{
    wheres.Add("phone_number LIKE @PatientMob");
    parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter(@"PatientMob", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
                   {
                       Value = PatientMobile.Text
                   });
}

...

string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE {0}", string.Join(" AND ", wheres));
```

And so on and so forth...

2. Check dynamically what's empty in the query

Something like this:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM message WHERE (LEN(@PatientMob) = 0 OR phone_number LIKE @PatientMob) and (LEN(@UserID) = 0 OR user_ID LIKE @UserID)", conn);
```

3. I see you're using `LIKE`, and admittedly I'm not one for MySQL so this could be way off, but it seems like you could be wrapping your parameters with whatever character designates a wildcard match. In T-SQL, that would look something like `column LIKE '%' + @param + '%'`. Of course, that won't be an exact match, but that sounds like it might be what you're looking for. In cases of empty search boxes, that will just result in `column LIKE '%%'`, which would match any values.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have a question regarding your first solution, should it be if (!string.IsNOTNullOrWhiteSpace ? 

From my understanding, your code is including the field in the select statement if the field IS empty, not if it is NOT empty.

Comment: @Bryan Nope, it's right as-is. That method returns `true` if the field *is* empty, and the exclamation mark is *not*-ing that. Thus, `if not true` will skip over that part if the field is empty.

Comment: That makes sense!  Thank you again. 

I am a little unsure where to place the 'string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE {0}", string.Join(" AND ", wheres));' line though.

It has to be before the MySqlCommand otherwise the 'query' string does not yet exist but if I put it before, then the 'wheres' string has not yet been created.

Comment: @Bryan Awesome. And good point, I've fixed it. I *imagine* `MySqlCommand` has an empty constructor and lets you set `CommandText` later on, but as I said I've never used MySQL. I've edited my answer to store the parameters in a separate list, that can then be added to the command after you create it. So now you would do something like `MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query)`, then on the next couple lines, add all those parameters that we stored in `parameters`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You are helping me understand it much better. 

It appears as though the query string is not seeing @PatientMob as a parameter and it is instead seeing it as text. Example: If I type in '12345' into the text box, when I click my button, it runs the following code "SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE patient_mobile LIKE @PatientMob" not "SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE patient_mobile LIKE 12345"

Comment: @Bryan I'm not completely sure I understand what you mean. Do you mean that you aren't getting the same results as you would have expected, or that the actual query command text isn't what you'd expect? You might have to bring the `@` symbol into the variable name--`new MySqlParameter("@PatientMob", ...`, if it's the former.

Comment: The query is is sending to the SQL server is not including the value from PatientMobile. No matter what number is typed into the  PatientMobile textbox, the code it tries to run on the SQL server is this exactly: `"SELECT * FROM MESSAGE WHERE PHONE_NUMBER LIKE @PatientMob".`

I assume at that point, the query string should be populated with the number entered into the text box, not just the text "@PatientMob"

Apologies if that doesn't make sense. I may not be explaining myself correctly.

Comment: @Bryan Nope, that makes sense. But that's actually not true: it's doing exactly what it should. Your command is actually sending two types of things off, the command text, and the parameters. It's a bit more difficult to see the parameters, since they're serialized from what is effectively a dictionary, but they should be carried along the wire as expected, then SQL will do that work server-side to put things together and make it work. It keeps everything strongly-typed for as long as it can, effectively.

Comment: For some reason I am getting a "fatal error during command execution" when running it that way. If I change the @PatientMob param in: wheres.add("phone_number like @PatientMob"); to a value such as '1234' and run it, it retrieves the results correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I will format the sql where string by myself. such as the code

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Phone.Text))
        {
            whereCriteria += " phone like @Phone";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter(@"phone", MySqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = Phone.Text;
        }
```