# How to troubleshooting a MySQL fatal error? C# front end

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, winforms

I am building a web form so that I am able to search within a mysql database using a select statement.

I have two text boxes - "UserID" and "PatientMobile" and a submit button. When the submit button is pressed, the following code is executed:

```
    protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {

            try
            {
                List<string> wheres = new List<string>();
                List<MySqlParameter> parameters = new List<MySqlParameter>();

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PatientMobile.Text))
                {
                    wheres.Add("PHONE_NUMBER = @PatientMob");
                    parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@PatientMob", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
                    {
                        Value = PatientMobile.Text
                    });
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserID.Text))
                {
                    wheres.Add("USER_ID = @UserID");
                    parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@UserID", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
                    {
                        Value = UserID.Text
                    });
                }


                string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM MESSAGE WHERE {0}", string.Join(" AND ", wheres));
                conn.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);

                MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adp.Fill(ds);
                grvCustomers.DataSource = ds;
                grvCustomers.DataBind();
                lbltotalcount.Text = grvCustomers.Rows.Count.ToString();

            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                ShowMessage(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();

            }
        }


    }
```

Everything looks fine to me, however when I run it I receive a fatal error.

If I replace the:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PatientMobile.Text))
                {
                    wheres.Add("PHONE_NUMBER = @PatientMob");
```

with

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PatientMobile.Text))
                {
                    wheres.Add("PHONE_NUMBER = 12345");
```

It runs fine. It only seems to not work if the query includes the @PatientMob.

I investigated this in wireshark and it seems like it isn't even passing the select statement to the mysql server.  If I remove the paramaterr and replace it with a text value (like above) it appears in wireshark and retrieves the results correctly.

I added a MessageBox.Show(query); so I could see the formatted query before it is run and it appears to be formatted correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: What fatal error do you receive?  Observation: you are populating but not using your `parameters` list. You need to use it when you bind values to your query.

Comment: The only error I get is "A fatal error occurred during execution" It doesn't really give any more details. 

The parameters are added to the 'wheres' string which is placed into the select query if the textbox/s aren't empty.

Comment: No, the parameters are not added to the wheres string. After string query = ... I suggest you Console.WriteLine(query) to see the query you are passing to the database. As you are not passing the 'parameters' list to the query, there is no substitution of @PatientMob. Either perform this substitution yourself or pass the parameters to the database with the query.

Comment: why do you have an extra `{` here `    protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {`
take a look at this MSDN documentation as well you are creating a parameters List<> which you is unnecessary in my opinion http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DJ CRAZE 
Good eye, I removed the extra `{`.
It's necessary for me to add these to a list in order for the program to work the way I intend it. Here's a bit of history as to why it was done that way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837125/select-query-from-multiple-textboxes-c-sharp/26837321?noredirect=1#comment42315694_26837321

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Blindingly obvious now that I look at it. 
I needed to add the parameters after the query string was created like so:

```
 string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM MESSAGE WHERE {0}", string.Join(" AND ", wheres));
                conn.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter(@"PatientMob", MySqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = PatientMobile.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter(@"UserID", MySqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = UserID.Text;
```

Working fine now!